# Pace is not working for every ajax call on page

Tags: ajax, pace.js

Using following code in my [page](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/):

```
 var paceOptions = {
    ajax: {
        trackMethods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'REMOVE'],
        restartOnRequestAfter: true
    }
};
```

Still it is not working for the small ajax request.

Comment: pace, what is this?

Comment: http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

Comment: Add your code please.